# How can I quickly relocate an entire virtual machine to a new location?

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

We are using Hyper-V in a clustered Server 2008 R2 environment with 3 identical hosts.  Virtual machines are stored on cluster shared volumes (CSV's) on a SAN backend connected via iSCSI.

What is the quickest, safest and most efficient way of moving virtual machines from one CSV to another?  Individual CSV's contain the VHD and the Virtual Machines sub-folder which contains XML, BIN and VSV files.

Virtual machines do not have any snapshots associated with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you upgrade your hyper-v cluster to Windows Server 2012R2. Once that's done you can perform storage migrations to move your vms between CSVs while they are running.

Comment: +1 thanks but his is currently not an option given licencing restrictions and the downtime from upgrading the entire cluster. I do agree this is definitely the way forward though, at a later date. We currently only want to move 2 of 20 virtual machines to a different CSV's.